# Using google api for search results in database

Tags: php, laravel, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I have a database table where I save Google's `placeID` 1 as the origin and `placeID` 2 as the destination. Later on, I use these fields from my database to pass them to Google's Directions API in order to represent a trip. My question is when a user comes to my site to look up their desired trip, he/she types A and B, how to get all trips from my database that are passing through A and B?

Comment: Hello! Did you found any solution?